# UiVideoEditorController change size

Tags: ios, xcode, video, uivideoeditorcontroller

I am captureing video use `AVCaptureSession`

And then Edit video using `UIVideoEditorController`

```
UIVideoEditorController *videoEditor = [[UIVideoEditorController alloc] init];
videoEditor.videoPath = recordedFile.path;
videoEditor.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame960x540;
videoEditor.delegate = self;
```

However Out video size is always return as 640 *360

Does anyone have idea why?

Comment: What is the value of sessionPreset set for AVCaptureSession?

Comment: AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720

Comment: I believe there are many other developer have same problem. https://devforums.apple.com/message/1120008#1120008

Comment: Have you inspected the video dimensions at recordedFile.path before feeding to Video Editor?

Comment: And the ticket is very old and says issue is in iPhone 4. Could be working OK in latest devices.

Comment: Yeah I have checked dimension and infact save on device too. 1280 * 720

Comment: Issue is still not fixed!

Comment: seems like output not following .scale of view/layer, maybe ?